# Azure DevOps build pipeline error on copy in post build event

Tags: azure-pipelines

I have built a simple pipeline to build my solution triggered by commits to the master branch using the Azure DevOps Pipelines.
I have a problem with the post build copy commands failing and returning errors

**my post build copy command:**

```
copy /Y "$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName)" "$(MY_PATH)$(TargetFileName)"
```

**I get the following errors:**

```
PostBuildEvent:
  copy /Y "D:\a\1\s\{some_path\file.dll}" "D:\a\1\s\BuildBin\{file.dll}"    
The system cannot find the path specified.
              0 file(s) copied.
```

the `MY_PATH` environmental variable is defined in the pipeline variables and using a "CmdLine" `echo %MY_PATH%` in the .yaml it echos the proper path in the console:

```
    Starting: CmdLine
==============================================================================
Task         : Command line
Description  : Run a command line script using Bash on Linux and macOS and cmd.exe on Windows
Version      : 2.177.3
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line
==============================================================================
Generating script.
Script contents:
echo %MY_PATH%
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
"C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe" /D /E:ON /V:OFF /S /C "CALL "D:\a\_temp\1db7603c-e3c0-4e32-924f-c5b1fc2cf96e.cmd""
D:\a\1\s\BuildBin\
Finishing: CmdLine
```

I have defined the `MY_PATH` to be `D:\a\1\s\BuildBin\` as I witnessed that this is the solution folder,
the paths in the error are correct.

Also I have tried running a script to create the BuildBin folder as I thought the folder does not exists but its not the reason as I run the following in the .yaml:

```
steps:
- script: echo mkdir D:\a\1\s\BuildBin
```

I cant find any info on the topic any where, just [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64018782/azure-pipelines-post-build-event-copy-command-failure) and it was not helpful.

I'm running the job in Windows Windows Server 2019 environment.
**Needless to say the solution builds on my pc with no problems, it also builds fine in the pipeline, its just the copy that fails.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and fixed it with this solution:

- for the pipeline yaml I added an additional param, could be any random name, I choose "AzureBuild" and set it to true:

[image]

- for the *.csproj file I added a Condition to Exec with that defined param in mind:

[image]

Now this post build events are only fired for local builds and not on Azure DevOps builds.

Comment: took me a year, because stackExchange does not list this as my question for some reason, but it solved my problem, thanks !